# Bubble sort complexity in Python

Tags: python, sorting

Im beginner in programming and Im learning Pyhon now. I saw on internet many bubble sorts using two for cycles. I understood it, but i wanted to write my own using while cycles. I finally wrote it and it work. There is complexity in my code and its probably bad. Some people said me, that it would be "faster" if i change it.
For example when I enter 6 unsorted numbers complexity is 25. But when I enter 6 sorted numbers (for example 1,2,3,4,5,6) complexity is still 25. When Im thinking about it complexity should be 6 or 5, no? I add some else in condition, but in didnt work.

```
lst=[]
number=""
while number!="k":
    number=input("Enter a nubmer (to end press K): ")
    if number!="k":
        number=int(number)
        lst.append(number)
print("Numbers before: ",lst,)

repetition=len(lst)-1
index=0
complexity=0
while repetition>0:
    repetition=repetition-1
    while index<=len(lst)-2:
        complexity=complexity+1
        if lst[index]>lst[index+1]:
              hlp=lst[index]
              lst[index]=lst[index+1]
              lst[index+1]=hlp
        index=index+1        
    index=0

print("Numbers after: ",lst,)
print("Complexity:",complexity,)
```

Can you please tell me where I should change it or directly how? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Answer (score 1):

Bubblesort algorithm complexity will always be `O(N^2)` in worst case irrespective of the programming language chosen to implement it.

Comment: I guess this is technically correct, but it's misleading. N^2 is not just worst case performance, that's the performance it will always have regardless of case.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is always N^2 runtime regardless of the order of the initial list, because it always goes through each element pair. The complexity should be the same with your code regardless of the order of the list you are sorting, so your complexity output is correct in that sense. You need a different sorting algorithm if you want better complexity.